# I am trying to download an internal submodule but not succeeding

Tags: github, codeql

We are using CodeQL on GitHub. I have 3 submodules. 1 main one and 2 submodules.

The first thing I tried is the happy path:

```
name: Checkout repository   
  uses: actions/checkout@v3   
  with:     
   submodules: true
```

This gave me the following error:

```
  Error: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyCompany/Genesis.git' does not exist
  Error: fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/MyCompany/Genesis.git' into submodule path 'D:/a/myprojectname/myprojectname/Submodules/Genesis' failed
  Failed to clone 'Submodules/Genesis'. Retry scheduled
  Error: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyCompany/SQLSourceControl.git' does not exist
  Error: fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/MyCompany/SQLSourceControl.git' into submodule path 'D:/a/myprojectname/myprojectname/Submodules/SqlSourceControl' failed
  Failed to clone 'Submodules/SqlSourceControl'. Retry scheduled
  Error: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyCompany/Genesis.git' does not exist
  Error: fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/MyCompany/Genesis.git' into submodule path 'D:/a/myprojectname/myprojectname/Submodules/Genesis' failed
  Failed to clone 'Submodules/Genesis' a second time, aborting
```

After doing a bit of research I found this answer: https://github.com/actions/checkout/discussions/928

I tried to do without the SSH since it's an internal repo within the same organization (it still gave the same error).

Then I found this: [Git submodule password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980298/git-submodule-password-prompt) but it gave the same error (git@ instead of https://).

I am out of ideas now. Can someone assist me please?